# Group and count with a set of values

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table with two foreign keys:

| exp_fk | bd_fk (nullable) |
| --- | --- |
| exp_id1 | bd_id1 |
| exp_id2 | bd_id2 |
| exp_id1 | bd_id2 |
| exp_id2 | bd_id2 |

There are no uniqueness constraints on this table.

I want to be able to be able to query for how many exp_id's have had more than 1 bd_fk.  So in the table above, I should get back a count of 1 since exp_id1 has two unique bd_id 's (bd_id1, bd_id2) but not for exp_id2 which has the same bd_fk.

I tried:

```
select exp_fk, bd_fk, count(*) from table
where bd_fk is not null 
group by exp_fk, bd_fk 
having count(*) > 1;
```

The problem is the having is not looking at unique bd_fk's.

Comment: Don't group by bd_fk, and use`count(distinct bd_fk)` instead `count(*)`

Comment: count(distinct...) will ignore nulls, if that's a concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery to find the relevant `exp_fk` values and count those:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  -- This subquery selects all the exp_fk values that have more than one unique bd_fk.
  SELECT exp_fk
  FROM table
  GROUP BY exp_fk
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT bd_fk) > 1
) AS subquery
```